# How to horizontally center a pie chart with plotly in R?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm new to plotly, trying to figure out how to get a piechart to be aligned at the center of the entire plot area.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

data_for_plot <-
  mtcars %>%
  count(cyl)

> data_for_plot

##   cyl  n
## 1   4 11
## 2   6  7
## 3   8 14


plot_ly(data_for_plot, labels = ~cyl, values = ~n, type = 'pie', hole = 0.05 ,textposition = 'outside',textinfo = 'percent') %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "my nice title is here", xanchor = "center"),
         showlegend = F,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE)) %>%
  layout(paper_bgcolor = "pink")
```

So I get this pie chart, which is not centered:
[image: plotly_piechart]

I assume that inside `layout()` I need something that refers to the piechart itself, to assign it with  `xanchor = "center"`. But I researched this and couldn't find an answer.

---

**Update on my attempts - 2020-01-18**

---

I've tested the majority of attributes in `layout()` and still couldn't find something that would work with `xanchor = "center"`. I've alse examined [plotly's reference guide](https://plotly.com/r/reference/pie/) but so far to no avail.

Comment: You may use `htmltools::` i.e. `p1c <- htmltools::div( p1, align="center" ); htmltools::save_html( p1c, "p1.html" )`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. Even after exporting to `.html` (using the solution you're hinting) it remains not centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that the solution involves setting up the `margin` attribute within `layout()`. The solution is based on this [hint](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-horizontally-center-a-pie-chart/49106/2?u=emman), referring to this [post](https://community.plotly.com/t/excessive-margins-in-graphs-how-to-remove/49094/2). Implementing this to `R` is done using the following code:

```r
plot_ly(data_for_plot, labels = ~cyl, values = ~n, type = 'pie', hole = 0.05 ,textposition = 'outside',textinfo = 'percent') %>%
  layout(title = list(text = "my nice title is here", xanchor = "center"),
         showlegend = F,
         margin = list(l = 20, r = 20),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE)) %>%
  layout(paper_bgcolor = "pink")
```

[image: pie_chart_centered]